# From hexadecimal string color to an RGB color

Tags: c++, colors, hex, rgb

How can i convert an `hexadecimal` string color `#FF0022` value into an `RGB` color in `C++`?

**from:**

```
#FF0022
```

**to**

```
r:255
g:0
b:34
```

I don't know how to do that, i have searched google without luck, please show me how to that so i can learn more about it.

Comment: i do not believe that you tried using google since there are tons of results (rgb string to c, rgb string to values, ...)

Comment: If you know what hexadecimals are, the rest is easy: split it in it's 3 constituent parts, FF, 00 and 22. Convert to decimals as appropriate.

Comment: https://github.com/kkaefer/css-color-parser-cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse through the string then use [strtol()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) to convert each set of two character to decimal.

Comment: @ooga that response is antithetical to the SO q&a community's mission "to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming". It's not our job to presumptuously dole out lessons in discipline

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> SplitWithCharacters(const std::string& str, int splitLength) {
  int NumSubstrings = str.length() / splitLength;
  std::vector<std::string> ret;

  for (int i = 0; i < NumSubstrings; i++) {
     ret.push_back(str.substr(i * splitLength, splitLength));
  }

  // If there are leftover characters, create a shorter item at the end.
  if (str.length() % splitLength != 0) {
      ret.push_back(str.substr(splitLength * NumSubstrings));
  }


  return ret;
}

struct COLOR {
  short r;
  short g;
  short b;
};

COLOR hex2rgb(string hex) {
  COLOR color;

  if(hex.at(0) == '#') {
      hex.erase(0, 1);
  }

  while(hex.length() != 6) {
      hex += "0";
  }

  std::vector<string> colori=SplitWithCharacters(hex,2);

  color.r = stoi(colori[0],nullptr,16);
  color.g = stoi(colori[1],nullptr,16);
  color.b = stoi(colori[2],nullptr,16);

  return color;
}

int main() {
  string hexcolor;

  cout << "Insert hex color: ";
  cin >> hexcolor;

  COLOR color = hex2rgb(hexcolor);

  cout << "RGB:" << endl;
  cout << "R: " << color.r << endl;
  cout << "G: " << color.g << endl;
  cout << "B: " << color.b << endl;

  return 0;
}
```